# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

По результатам опроса среди населения (,) прошедшее мероприятие стало поводом для гордости...

Я почему-то уверена, что не нужна, но она там стоит!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По результатам опроса среди населения (,) прошедшее мероприятие стало поводом для гордости...Вполне может быть вводным сочетанием со значением источника сообщения:как говорят результаты опроса. Вот если бы было "по результатам опроса выпустили бюллетень", запятой не было бы.